# Calculating probabilities of balls arrangements

Tags: probability

> There are 3 different sizes of white balls and 3 different sizes of
>   green balls. When these 6 balls are laid out in a line so that the
>   three white balls can be placed in adjacent positions, how many
>   arrangements of all the balls can be made?

From what I understand, `three white balls can be placed in adjacent positions` only has 4 arrangements :

```
WWWGGG
GWWWGG
GGWWWG
GGGWWW
G : Green, W : White
```

But the answer group doesn't have any `4`, so I know I'm misunderstanding something here.

Please point it out for me!

Comment: But the green balls are distinguishable and hence you will have to add 3! to each of these configuration.

Comment: @satishramanathan The white balls are also distinguishable.

Comment: @Calculus, your are right, they can be permuted in 3! ways.  Sorry.

Comment: @satishramanathan There is nothing to be sorry for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **different sizes** is where the key of the question lies. I'll show you with an example what I mean.

Suppose we have $2$ white balls ($W$ and $w$) and $2$ green balls ($G$ and $g$) where uppercase letters are used for differentiating ball sizes.

Notice that, as they have different sizes they can't be treated as the same object. This means that the combination

$$WwGg$$

Is not the same as

$$WwgG$$

So the problem is that you are not taking into account the differences in ball sizes which adds many more combinations. Can you work it out from here?

Comment: So there are 4 possible orders like I said above, and 2 color of choices, we have : 4 * (3!) * (3!). Am I right?

Comment: That's it! The total amount of combinations is then 144. Does it match with your answers?

Comment: You have 4 possible combinations which match the restrictions of the problem and for each of those you have 36 possible orders taking sizes into account.

Comment: Yes it matches the answer, just wanted to make sure that I understand the problem correctly